# Is there a need to remove entries from mapping?

Tags: solidity, gas, mapping

I am adding approximately 3 ~ 5 new entries into the mapping, while the old one will be obsolete after a week.

If the mapping grow larger, is it going to consume more gasses?

Is there a need for me to remove them since they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 3):

You pass gas to store the value in the first place. There are no future charges for keeping the data there.

That said, you can get a gas *refund* for deleting the existing data. That can only offset gas used for a new transaction. So if you can manage to delete the old ones while adding the new ones *in the same transaction*, you'll save gas (and thus ether) by doing so.

Comment: smarx, thanks for the answer. So adding an entry into a mapping (regardless if it has 0 or 1000000 entries) will always consume the same amount of gas right?

Comment: That's correct.