# Can gas refunds for deleted storage be used as transient storage?

Tags: solidity, storage, memory

I know there are previous answers around this, but things have changed new EIP's:

Right now I'm using an array of structs, for something I only do in memory. It's very messy code and would be much simpler as mapping (with no arrays) — but I'm avoiding that due to the gas for storage writes.
If I instead used a mapping, and deleted the mapping at the end of the function, would gas be comparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can delete a mapping because Solidity does not know the keys for the mapping. However, individual keys and what they map to can be deleted: If `a` is a mapping, then `delete a[x]` will delete the value stored at `x`. Deleting a mapping entry does result in a gas refund, and deleting a variable generally refunds 15,000 gas up to a maximum of half the gas cost of the transaction.

See:

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/types.html

[Is there a need to remove entries from mapping?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56853/is-there-a-need-to-remove-entries-from-mapping)

https://soliditydeveloper.com/design-pattern-solidity-free-up-unused-storage